# mongochef azure document db query issue

Tags: mongodb, azure-cosmosdb

I am currently using MongoChef (4.3.0) to access an Azure Document DB ([using DocumentDB protocol support for MongoDB](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/documentdb-mongodb-mongochef/)).

The data in question is from an Application Insights continuous export has the following type of data within (there is other data there but this is the key part i am interested in...)

```
{
    ... other fields ...
    "request" : [
        {
            "name" : "GET /images/loading_man.gif", 
            "count" : NumberInt(1), 
            "responseCode" : NumberInt(200), 
            "success" : NumberInt(1), 
            "url" : "http://<removed>.cloudapp.azure.com/<something>/images/loading_man.gif"
            ... other fields ...
        } 
    ]
    ... other fields ...
}
```

Using MongoChef I can perform some basic query like the following without issue;

```
{ "request": { $exists: true } }
```

but anything more complicated seems to return nothing or not run at all

```
{ "request.0.url": { $exists: true } } 

{ "request.0.url": /.*man.*/i }
```

If I Export this data and Import it to my local MongoDb I am indeed able to perform such searches on the data in question without issue.

Any ideas how I could perform this type of search on the data in question without needing to export it?.

(this is a programming issue, because I want to do the above in a python program!)

Comment: Try array index syntax so instead of `request.0.url`, try `request[0]["url"]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well it looks like all I needed to do was use $elemMatch!

```
{ "request": { $elemMatch: {url:/.*man.*/i } }}
```

this is as I understand the recommended way but also 'faster'?

Comment: Cool! Glad you got it to work. Keep in mind that if the element exists but is Null, neither approach will trap that so you either need to be 100% certain that you never store a Null or you need to add a clause to your filter to check for this.